# Is there a minlength validation attribute in HTML?

Tags: html, validation

It seems the `minlength` attribute for an `<input>` field doesn't work.

Is there any other attribute in HTML with the help of which I can set the minimal length of a value for fields?

Comment: It won't be the answer for every field, but if you just want to make sure a value is there you can use the "required" attribute. <input type="text" name="input1" required="required" />

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533053/textarea-character-limit/5607015#comment21177768_5607015

Comment: It doesn't exist, but let's make a fuss and get it in! https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=20557

Comment: You need to use JS/Jquery if you want to do a full implementation (eg. required, minlength, error message when submitting etc). Safari still does not fully support even the required attribute, and only Chrome and Opera support minLength. eg see http://caniuse.com/#search=required

Answer (score 1412, accepted):

You can use the [`pattern` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090825/forms.html#attr-input-pattern). The [`required` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090825/forms.html#attr-input-required) is also needed, otherwise an input field with an empty value will be excluded from [constraint validation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#constraint-validation).

```
<input pattern=".{3,}"   required title="3 characters minimum">
<input pattern=".{5,10}" required title="5 to 10 characters">
```

If you want to create the option to use the pattern for "empty, or minimum length", you could do the following:

```
<input pattern=".{0}|.{5,10}" required title="Either 0 OR (5 to 10 chars)">
<input pattern=".{0}|.{8,}"   required title="Either 0 OR (8 chars minimum)">
```

Comment: +1 for using html5 instead of jQuery. I just wanted to add that the title attribute allows you to set the message to display to the user if the pattern is not met. Otherwise a default message will be shown.

Comment: @J.Money It still says "Please match the requested format: <title>". Is there a way to bypass the prior default message?

Comment: Unfortunately this is **not supported for textareas**.

Comment: Totally works, but the error you get when not meeting the pattern requirements is: "Please match the requested format" or something along those lines.  It begs the follow up question:  how do you customize the error message :-)

Comment: @RandyGreencorn It's the browser's choice whether or not they use the `title` attribute as the error message: *User agents **may** use the contents of this attribute, if it is present, when informing the user that the pattern is not matched…* http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090825/forms.html#attr-input-pattern

Comment: I am testing with Chromium and when I insert 2 characters, it correctly tells me "please match the requested format", but when I insert 0 characters it doesn't complain and submits the form :-(

Comment: Would eg `<input pattern=".{5}" maxlength="10" required title="5 to 10 characters">` be a better example, as avoids waiting until submit to satisfy max length condition?

Comment: is there a way for setting a custom error message is the validation is not ok ?

Comment: @ChaZ @Basj You can add a custom error message by adding the following attribute: `oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Your message')"`

Comment: on a related note, this is a great website to test your Regular expressions before including them on your HTML5 forms - [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/)

Comment: on firefox and chrome add a title attribute to the field in order to append some information to the standard error message. For example `title="8 characters minimum"` will display "Please match the requested format: 8 characters minimum". Saves on inline javascript.

Comment: It is noteworthy that: since the pattern attributes executes the regular expression; you should use  ^ and $ as necessary. E.G ` pattern="^[0-9]{2}$" ` permits EXACTLY two integers in the input field.

Comment: @knocte make sure the input type is 'text'  and the required attribute is set.    The pattern attribute will not be effective for some standard input type e.g type='number' or type='url'

Comment: If you enters an invalid input and you're using `setCustomValidity`, then it will continue to show you the error message even after you corrected the input. You can use the following `onchange` method to counter this. **`oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Field must contain min. 5 characters')"  onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"`**

Comment: Is there any way to implement this in Safari because Safari doesn't support these attributes? 
Seems like Js and jQuery are only the solutions for safari.

Comment: Required attribute not working on ios devices. And the pattern attributes does not work without the attribute required. This doesnt work on ios devices.

Comment: It doesn't works if the input type is number. Any solution for this?

Comment: If you are using a pattern for "empty, or minimum length", then you need to remove 'required' (at least for Chrome).

Comment: Do you need to specify `required` for "empty or minimum length"? "The required attribute is also needed, otherwise an input field with an empty value will be excluded from constraint validation." would seem to indicate that you don't.

Comment: Ive been searching for a solution for this: **pattern=".{5,}[0-9]"** where I want minimum 5 characters & can only be 0-9, no spaces, no "**+**" symbols. But **.{5,}[0-9]** allows letters in the middle for some reason. Example: **123kh678**. Any ideas?

Comment: For some reason https://regex101.com/ fails to properly parse `.{0}|.{5,10}` solution, always getting group 1 (empty string). If global flag is added, multiple matches are found inbetween characters.

Answer (score 175):

There **is** a `minlength` property in [the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-maxlength-and-minlength-attributes) now, as well as the `validity.tooShort` interface.

Both are now enabled in recent versions of all modern browsers. For details, see https://caniuse.com/#search=minlength.

Comment: I see this, but still it is not working for me. I have required set as well, but still not validating against the minlength. not sure why.

Answer (score 24):

**Here is HTML5-only solution** (if you want minlength 5, maxlength 10 character validation)

**http://jsfiddle.net/xhqsB/102/**

```html
    <form>
      <input pattern=".{5,10}">
      <input type="submit" value="Check"></input>
    </form>
```

Comment: How to set a custom error message if the field is not Ok?

Comment: For custom message add `title` attribute with the required message.

Comment: The same `pattern` answer has been given [a few months earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10294291/1269037). How is this answer better?

Comment: @DanDascalescu He didn't have form tags and a clear explanation. I also included a working jsfiddle demo. (btw Stackoverflow rules say that it's not forbidden to give similar answers as long as it's helpful to the community)

Comment: One way to give an even better answer is to include the demo here on SO as a [runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, there it is. It's like maxlength. W3.org documentation:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-minlength

In case `minlength` doesn't work, use the `pattern` attribute as mentioned by @Pumbaa80 for the `input` tag.

**For textarea:**
For setting max; use `maxlength` and for min go to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184791/how-to-apply-min-and-max-on-textarea/24640346#24640346).

You will find here both for max and min.

Answer (score 12):

I used maxlength and minlength with or without `required` and it worked for me very well for HTML5.

```html
<input id="passcode" type="password" minlength="8" maxlength="10">
```

`

Answer (score 6):

`minlength` attribute is now widely supported in [most of the browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-minlength).

```
<input type="text" minlength="2" required>
```

But, as with other HTML5 features, IE11 is missing from this panorama. So, if you have a wide IE11 user base, consider using the `pattern` HTML5 attribute that is supported almost across the board in [most browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern) (including IE11).

To have a nice and uniform implementation and maybe extensible or dynamic (based on the framework that generate your HTML), I would vote for the `pattern` attribute:

```
<input type="text" pattern=".{2,}" required>
```

There is still **a small usability catch** when using `pattern`. The user will see a non-intuitive (very generic) error/warning message when using `pattern`. See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4cdwkgf/) or below:

```html
<h3>In each form type 1 character and press submit</h3>
</h2>
<form action="#">
  Input with minlength: <input type="text" minlength="2" required name="i1">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br>
<form action="#">
  Input with patern: <input type="text" pattern=".{2,}" required name="i1">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

For example, in Chrome (but similar in most browsers), you will get the following error messages:

```
Please lengthen this text to 2 characters or more (you are currently using 1 character)
```

by using `minlength` and

```
Please match the format requested
```

by using `pattern`.

Answer (score 5):

The minLength attribute (unlike maxLength) does not exist natively in HTML5. However, there a some ways to validate a field if it contains less than x characters.

An example is given using jQuery at this link: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/minlength

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
                debug: true,
                success: "valid"
            });;
        </script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#myform").validate({
                    rules: {
                        field: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 3
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="myform">
            <label for="field">Required, Minimum length 3: </label>
            <input class="left" id="field" name="field" />
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Validate!" />
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

I notice that sometimes in Chrome when autofill is on and the fields are field by the autofill browser build in method, it bypasses the minlength validation rules, so in this case you will have to disable autofill by the following attribute:

**autocomplete="off"**

```
<input autocomplete="new-password" name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="12" minlength="6" required />
```

Answer (score 4):

Not HTML5, but practical anyway: if you happen to use **AngularJS**, you can use [`ng-minlength`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) (or `data-ng-minlength`) for both inputs and textareas. See also [this Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/GotWYIwosmrokXCul249).

Answer (score 4):

My solution for textarea using jQuery and combining HTML5 required validation to check the minimum length.

#### minlength.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form textarea[minlength]').on('keyup', function(){
    e_len = $(this).val().trim().length
    e_min_len = Number($(this).attr('minlength'))
    message = e_min_len <= e_len ? '' : e_min_len + ' characters minimum'
    this.setCustomValidity(message)
  })
})
```

#### HTML

```
<form action="">
  <textarea name="test_min_length" id="" cols="30" rows="10" minlength="10"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

See *http://caniuse.com/#search=minlength*. Some browsers may not support this attribute.

---

If the value of the "type" is one of them:

**text, email, search, password, tel, or URL** (warning: not include **number** | **no browser support "tel"** now - 2017.10)

Use the **minlength**(/ maxlength) attribute. It specifies the minimum number of characters.

For example,

```
<input type="text" minlength="11" maxlength="11" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="input your phone number">
```

Or use the "pattern" attribute:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{11}" placeholder="input your phone number">
```

If the "type" is **number**, although **minlength**(/ maxlength) is not be supported, you can use the **min**(/ max) attribute instead of it.

For example,

```
<input type="number" min="100" max="999" placeholder="input a three-digit number">
```

Answer (score 2):

New version:

It extends the use (textarea and input) and fixes bugs.

```
// Author: Carlos Machado
// Version: 0.2
// Year: 2015
window.onload = function() {
    function testFunction(evt) {
        var items = this.elements;
        for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
            if ((items[j].tagName == "INPUT" || items[j].tagName == "TEXTAREA") && items[j].hasAttribute("minlength")) {
                if (items[j].value.length < items[j].getAttribute("minlength") && items[j].value != "") {
                    items[j].setCustomValidity("The minimum number of characters is " + items[j].getAttribute("minlength") + ".");
                    items[j].focus();
                    evt.defaultPrevented;
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    items[j].setCustomValidity('');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
    var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;
    if(!isChrome) {
        var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
        for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
            forms[i].addEventListener('submit', testFunction,true);
            forms[i].addEventListener('change', testFunction,true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this elegant updated solution. Does it work outside of Chrome/Opera since they don't support minlength? http://caniuse.com/#search=minlength  I just tested it on Mac Safari and it doesn't work :( I see you are adding the eventListener for non Chrome/Opera browsers, so maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: After debugging Safari it seems that var items = this.elements;  is returning the FORMS collection, not the items in the form. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

Following @**user123444555621** pinned answer.

There is a `minlength` attribute in HTML5 but for some reason it may not always work as expected.

**I had a case where my input type text did not obey the `minlength="3"` property.**

By using the `pattern` attribute I managed to fix my problem.
**Here's an example of using pattern to ensure minlength validation:**

```js
const folderNameInput = document.getElementById("folderName");

folderNameInput.addEventListener('focus', setFolderNameValidityMessage);
folderNameInput.addEventListener('input', setFolderNameValidityMessage);

function setFolderNameValidityMessage() {
  if (folderNameInput.validity.patternMismatch || folderNameInput.validity.valueMissing) {
      folderNameInput.setCustomValidity('The folder name must contain between 3 and 50 chars');
  } else {
      folderNameInput.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}
```

```css
:root {
  --color-main-red: rgb(230, 0, 0);
  --color-main-green: rgb(95, 255, 143);
}

form input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: none;
}

form input:invalid:focus {
  border-bottom-color: var(--color-main-red);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 var(--color-main-red);
}

form input:not(:invalid):focus {
  border-bottom-color: var(--color-main-green);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 var(--color-main-green);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input
    type="text"
    id="folderName"
    placeholder="Your folder name"
    spellcheck="false"
    autocomplete="off"
    
    required
    minlength="3"
    maxlength="50"
    pattern=".{3,50}"
  />
  <button type="submit" value="Create folder">Create folder</button>
</form>
```

**For further details**, here's the MDN link to the HTML pattern attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this JavaScript code, [minlength.js]:

```
window.onload = function() {
    function testaFunction(evt) {
        var elementos = this.elements;
        for (var j = 0; j < elementos.length; j++) {
            if (elementos[j].tagName == "TEXTAREA" && elementos[j].hasAttribute("minlength")) {
                if (elementos[j].value.length < elementos[j].getAttribute("minlength")) {
                    alert("The textarea control must be at least " + elementos[j].getAttribute("minlength") + " characters.");
                    evt.preventDefault();
                };
            }
        }
    }
    var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        forms[i].addEventListener('submit', testaFunction, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, in which I validate the most manually and using Firefox (43.0.4), `minlength` and `validity.tooShort` are not available unfortunately.

Since I only need to have minimum lengths stored to proceed, an easy and handy way is to assign this value to another valid attribute of the input tag. In that case then, you can use `min`, `max`, and `step` properties from [type="number"] inputs.

Rather than storing those limits in an array it's easier to find it stored in the same input instead of getting the element id to match the array index.

Answer (score 1):

If desired to make this behavior, always **show a small prefix on the input field** or **the user can't erase a prefix**:

```
   // prefix="prefix_text"
   // If the user changes the prefix, restore the input with the prefix:
   if(document.getElementById('myInput').value.substring(0,prefix.length).localeCompare(prefix))
       document.getElementById('myInput').value = prefix;
```

Answer (score 1):

I used max and min then required, and it worked for me very well, but what am not sure is if it is a but coding method.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="13" name ="idnumber" class="form-control"  minlength="13" required>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"a but coding method"*?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `minlength` in input tag or you can regex pattern to check the number of character or even you can take the input and check the length of the character and then you can restrict based upon your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**Smartest Way for *maxlength***

```js
$("html").on("keydown keyup change", "input", function(){
    var maxlength=$(this).attr('maxlength');    
    if(maxlength){  
        var value=$(this).val();
        if(value.length<=maxlength){
            $(this).attr('v',value);
        }
        else{
            $(this).val($(this).attr('v'));
        }   
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" maxlength="10">
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31494183)

Answer (score 0):

I've used the follow tag with numbers:

```
<input type="tel" class="form-control" name="Extension" id="Extension" required maxlength="4" minlength="4" placeholder="4 Digits" />
```

Answer (score -4):

Add both a maximum and a minimum value. You can specify the range of allowed values:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="999" />
```