# Setting minimum password length

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, passwords

I'm trying to set a minimum password lenght for a login page; however, it seems that the only attribute the password (input) tag has is maxlength. I know you can use the new pattern or min attribute, but I need something that works in IE 9. Is there a simple/replacement way to solve this or will I have to use strlen?

Comment: @JonathandeM. What if JS is disabled?

Comment: Use js, but validate server-side as well

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from javascript when there is much easier ways to solve this issue.

Comment: Javascript is unsafe for this kind of thing. Only use for client-side operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function CheckLength(name) {

            var password = document.getElementById(name).value;

            if (password.length < 4)

                alert('should have miniumum 4 chars');

        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="password" id="txtpassword" name="txtpassword" />
    <input type="submit" name="txtSubmit" onclick="CheckLength('txtpassword') " />
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess the only way in IE 9 and below is to check the array length rather than checking it in the input tag.

Answer (score 5):

Some Ok answers so far.

However, this is much more a concern server-side than client. I would not be difficult to "hack" the markup or Javascript to allow a short password.

You should always check server-side as well to make sure nothing weird is going on.

To sum it all up: Use Javascript to make sure the password is longer than the minimum length and recheck it server-side to make sure the jsfunction was not bypassed in any way.

Comment: _You should always check server-side as well to make sure nothing weird is going on._ +1

Answer (score 2):

One liner:

```
<input type="text" onKeyPress="return ( this.value.length < 10 );"/>
```

This can be used to implement `maxlength` in Internet Explorer but you should validate the input server side, too.

Answer (score 2):

You must use **server side solution** for this problem as you never know whether user has js enabled or not..

Comment: use both, js for user comfort, and a fallback to server-side.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281962/is-there-a-minlength-validation-attribute-in-html5), try this:

```
<input pattern=".{3,}" required title="3 characters minimum">
<input pattern=".{5,10}" required title="5 to 10 characters">
```