# How to apply min and max on textarea?

Tags: html, forms, textarea, character, min

Is there a way in HTML5 forms to add a min and max character to a textarea? It seems I can apply it to a regular input using pattern.

```
<input pattern=".{3,}" title="3 characters minimum">
```

Am I looking at a jquery solution?

Comment: see the link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281962/is-it-minlength-in-html5

Comment: here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/xhqsB/104/

Answer (score 43):

HTML5 solution, min 5, max 20 characters

just set the attribute maxlength="20" and  minlength="5" to the textarea tag

http://jsfiddle.net/xhqsB/603/

```
   <form>
      <textarea maxlength="20" minlength="5" required></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Check"></input>
   </form>
```

Comment: Note that this is [currently not well supported by browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=minlength)

Comment: Now it looks like all the browsers except IE/Edge

Comment: This did not work for me. I had to add the `required` property to the `textarea` and that fired the validation. I'm using Google Chrome, Version 64.0.3282.167 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: Now that this is supported by [90% of web users](https://caniuse.com/#search=minlength), this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

**For max:** see below code
Use `maxlength` for maximum character.

```
maxlength="nuber_of_characters"
```

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-textarea-element

**For min:** [source](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?757838-minimum-characters-in-text-area-how-to)
Use Javascript as below: 
use id attribute in `<textarea>`. Set id attribute to minle(for eg) ie `id="minle"`

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="80" maxlength="200" required id="minle" >
</textarea>
```

and put following js code segment in your `form` tag

```
  <form action="mango.php" method="post" id="form12" onsubmit="var text = document.getElementById('minle').value; if(text.length < 80) { alert('put more info!'); return false; } return true;">
```

This allow user to input no. of characters from 80 to 200.

Comment: action="" is not valid in html5

Comment: @dstonek yes it is, but i have intentionally left it blank to draw more focus on validatoin. Ok I am editing now.

Answer (score 2):

```
<textarea
  name="myTextarea"
  minlength="10"
  maxlength="50"
  required
></textarea>
```

You need to have `minlength`, `maxlength` AND `required` in `textarea`

Comment: ```required``` is mandatory, else ```minlength``` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 solution, min 5, max 10 characters

**http://jsfiddle.net/xhqsB/102/**

```
<form>
  <input pattern=".{5,10}">
  <input type="submit" value="Check"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: And what about `min`?

Comment: was more the validation - in html5 I use required pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*" /> for email addresses is great but textareas do not have this but I would have though a max-min in html5 was pretty desirable.

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu nice, but *Is there a way in HTML5 forms to add a mix and min character to a **textarea**?*

Answer (score 1):

You can use minlength=20. Do not use "".

For exp true: `minlength=20`
False exp: `minlength="20"`