# How do I get javascript validation on form input working?

Tags: javascript

Just trying to do a simple maximum length of `fName` to not exceed over 10.

I've been looking for online examples. Can't find a common ground in anywhere on any examples I find.

I'm able to submit anything except an empty text (because of required)

```
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript">

     var x = document.regoForm.fName.value;
      if (x > 1)
     {
        alert( "too big" );
        return false;
     }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="regoForm" id="regoForm" method="post">

    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="fName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" required placeholder="John" name="fName"
        id="fName"/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </p>

</form>
```

Comment: @ArunPJohny I did nothing is happening

Comment: Still there are multiple issues... you need to have a event handler which can check the value when user enters the value etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431426/how-to-set-max-length-of-6-and-minimum-length-of-6-in-a-textbox

Comment: You can't return when not in a function, your form isn't found by the script

Comment: Learn some basic js before posting. No one could help if you don't know the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added an onclick handler to the button, and insert the code into a function.

And if you want to check the length, not the value, then you should use the `.length` to get the length of the text.

Try this

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkNameLength() {
            if (document.getElementById('fName').value.length > 10) {
                alert("too big");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="regoForm" id="regoForm" method="post">
        <p>
            <label for="fName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" required placeholder="John" name="fName" id="fName"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitBtn" onclick="return checkNameLength()">
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use built in methods like `maxlength`

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" required placeholder="John" name="fName" id="fName"/>
```