# maxlength and minlength Not validating HTML textbox in IE

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>  
      <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form> 
        <input type="text"   placeholder="Mobile Number" required=""  style="width: 263px;" maxlength="10" minlength="10">
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

I'm trying to restrict the textbox validation by using `maxlength` and `minlength` CSS attributes, it is not working in IE (although working on other browsers).

Answer (score 4):

It appears that `minlength` [is not supported](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/18-minlength.html) in [most current browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=minlength). There is a promising looking workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281962/is-there-a-minlength-validation-attribute-in-html5) that you can try to use. Using `maxlength` and the workaround, your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (javascript) solution:

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
  var errors = false;
  if(document.getElementById("mobile").val().length() != 10) {
    errors=true;
    alert("number must be 10 characters");
  }else{
    errors=false;
  }
  if(errors==false){
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
  }
}
</script>

<form method="post" id="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <input type="text" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" style="width: 263px;" maxlength="10" minlength="10">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```