# Phalcon Regex validation password doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, validation, passwords, phalcon

I don't understand why my Regex doesn't work. There is always an error message for any passwords.

```
 $this->add('password', new RegexValidator(array(
           'pattern' => '.{0}|.{4,}',
           'message' => '0 or 4 char minimum'
 )));
```

The error is : 0 or 4 char minimum.

Comment: What, exactly, is the error message?

Comment: this : 0 or 4 char minimum. This is my message

Comment: That's important information that should be in your question. Comments are meant to be temporary. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: From what I can tell your regular expression is invalid, so it is always failing. What do you want the regex to validation - between 0 and 4 characters?

Comment: I need the same things than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281962/is-there-a-minlength-validation-attribute-in-html5

Comment: Then do not use `required` (and it will be allowed to be empty), and use `pattern=".{4,}"`. Does it work then?

Comment: I know that. It's ok for my view side. But now I'm doing a validation server side with Phalcon. And this Regex doesn't work. I don't know why the regex works well in my view and doesn't work with Phalcon regex Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Regex

Comment: You don't need a regex for this, `empty` and `strlen` could accomplish this and would probably be easier to read.

Comment: @chris85 I'm using Phalcon PHP so I have to use the "validator" class. And I can't use PresenceOf() and StringLength() class because I need to validate the password if he is nul or if this length is >= 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine the [StringLenght](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Validation_Validator_StringLength.html) validation with the `allowEmpty` option:

```
$badPassMessage = 'Define a password using exactly 4 characters or leave it empty!';
$validation->add('password', new StringLength(array(
      'max' => 4,
      'min' => 4,
      'allowEmpty' => true,
      'messageMaximum' => $badPassMessage,
      'messageMinimum' => $badPassMessage
)));
```

BONUS

I'd recommend you to always test your patterns with this excellent tool:

[regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com/#pcre)

Always make sure that the regex flavor is set to `pcre (php)`.

Comment: Oh awesome. The allowEmpty parameter is the solution. So now I can use the StringLenght validation https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Validation_Validator_StringLength.html with the allowEmpty parameter. Thanks a lot !!!!!

Comment: OK nice :). But i'm not using the max parameter. Just the min.

Comment: @John have you tested if does allow 3 char length passwords? From my understanding you don't want that right?! I believe the default `min` is 0