# Missing "minLength" in ReactDom in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

React JSX:

```
<input
    type="password"
    name="password"
    value={this.state.password}
    minLength={2}
    maxLength={4}
    required="required"
    onChange={e => this.handleOnChange(e)}
    placeholder="Password"/>
```

handler:

```
handleOnChange = (e) => {
    console.dir(e.target)
    console.dir(e.target.minLength) // ==> expected value is 2, but undefined
    console.dir(e.target.maxLength) // ==> 4
```

In Chrome, I'm able to find the "minLength". But in Safari, missing key-value paris of "minLength".

"maxLength" does exist.

I don't have a grip of this problem, Does Safari not implement "minLength"?

Version:

- Safari 9.1.1 (11601.6.17)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, Safari doesn't implement it: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-minlength

You might want to try using the pattern attribute or one of the other answer to this question: [Is there a minlength validation attribute in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281962/is-there-a-minlength-validation-attribute-in-html5)