# How to give phone number range using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have registration form with few fields.

Having phone number field. How can i give phone number range using `jquery`.

User should enter between 10 to 15 digits range.

Here is my code

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]{10}" name="mobileno" 
title="Enter your mobile number" class="form-control1" required placeholder="">
```

Thanks

Comment: try [input mask](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Comment: <input type="mask" /> Like this?

Comment: are u looking for an input that allows entries between 10 and 15 chars?

Comment: Here what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281962/is-there-a-minlength-validation-attribute-in-html5

Answer (score 2):

Use, `maxlength` and `minlength` in input attribute.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{10}" name="mobileno" title="Enter your mobile number" class="form-control1" minlength="10" maxlength="15" required placeholder="">
```