# how to restrict number of characters text input not counting spaces in html form

Tags: regex, forms, validation, maxlength

Im searching the way to restric the number of characters allowed at a text type input of a form, but also not counting spaces.

If I use `maxlength='5'` then a string like **a b c** counts 5 characters, so I would like to be able to introduce a string like **a b c d e** where written characters are 5 and spaces are not counting as characters.

I can not restric to `maxlength='9'`, because there could be some other patterns like **ab cd e** or **a b cd e** etc...

I think that maybe `pattern` should be a solution, but I can not find the way how....

**UPDATE** I tried answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734105/html5-minimum-character-length-validation-ignoring-spaces-and-tabs) but it didn't help me, so the solution comes from the comments below:

Comment: You can simplify the pattern in the link I provided above with the following pattern: `\s*(\S\s*){5}`

Comment: Thanks @ctwheels I put that the word should be between 8 and 13 characters not counting the spaces: `pattern='\s*(\S\s*){8,13}'`