# Angular 10 reactive form Validators minLength to ignore spaces

Tags: angular, angular-validator

Is there any solution to use `Validators.minLength(6)` but to ignore spaces ?

E.G: `1234 5` this would validate but it shouldn't as I'm looking to validate 6 digits without spaces E.G: `1234 56`

Thanks.

Comment: You can create custom validator if there is no better solution.

Answer (score 1):

As I've searched for Angular specific I couldn't find any answers, after searching more generic `html minlength validation digits without spaces` I've found something that pointed me to a solution. ref:[html input pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734105/html5-minimum-character-length-validation-ignoring-spaces-and-tabs)

It's the html input pattern attribute which we can also use in angular so my solution is:

`Validators.pattern('\\s*(\\S\\s*){16,}')`

The above worked really nice for me!

Answer (score 1):

While your pattern approach works, it is hardly considerable as "readable". In this case I would recommend you to look into [Custom Validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators).

Something like the following should be what you are looking for.

```js
export function maxPrunedLength(length: number): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const prunedValueLength = control.value.replaceAll(' ','').length;
    return prunedValueLength > length 
      ? {forbiddenName: {value: control.value}} 
      : null;
  };
}
```

Comment: That was my initial thought but I think in this case is unnecessary, Validator pattern a build in function so why re-invented the wheel? What is unreadable about regex ?

Answer (score 0):

There is not. `Validators.minLength(6)` is a factory, that creates a function, which takes a FormControl and returns an error object or null - also called ValidatorFn. You can make use of it, by altering the provided control.

```
export class CustomValidators {
  static minLengthIgnoreWhitespace(length: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      const modifiedControl: FormControl = new FormControl(control.value.replace(/\s/g, ''));
      return Validators.minLength(length)(modifiedControl);
    };
  }
}
```