# How to get input of exact length?

Tags: javascript, html

How to set the input value of a text field to be exact?
I want to get a document number of exactly 10 digit from user.
The following two does not work at the same time:

```
var input = document.createElement("input"); 
input.setAttribute("min","10") 
input.setAttribute("max","10")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a minlength validation attribute in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281962/is-there-a-minlength-validation-attribute-in-html5)

Comment: I'd use `<input type="text" pattern="\d{10}" title="10-digit number" />`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** min/max are only valid on `type="number"` or `type="date"` inputs.

This can be done with pure html. You can set the field to `type="number"` and require the min value to be `1000000000` (10 digits) and a max value of `9999999999` (also 10 digits). Then just tack on the `required` parameter on the field. The form won't submit unless it validates due to the `required` parameter.

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="number" min="1000000000" max="9999999999" required>
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Another thing we can do is use a `pattern` on a `text input` with `required`:

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required>
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: `999999999999999999999999999999999999999` is submitted, but its length is not 10 as OP requested

Comment: Instead of 100000000 and 999999999 can't we just specify the required length of input

Comment: If you use a pattern as shown in the second example, that one blocks letters as well.

Comment: Okk will it then. Thanks