# How to replace an empty string with static content

Tags: php, html, replace

I'm currently running a forum-like site where if a user leaves the post completely empty and hits the post button, an error is thrown. What I would like, is to replace that error (an empty string) with static content. So, for example, that automatically the words `No comment` get posted, instead of an error being thrown.

The relevant code currently is:

```php
if ($stripped_whitespace == '') {
    error($config['error']['tooshort_body']);
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just set a minimum length on the field - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281962/is-there-a-minlength-validation-attribute-in-html5

Answer (score 0):

I think first we have to know which variable holds user content before sending to storage (database), let say.

```
 if($_POST['comment']){
    //true so send $comment to database;
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];  // you have to validate this <--- for sure :)
}else{
   //false, so instead of error
    $comment = 'No Comment';
}
```

Comment: Right, the responsible variable is called 'body'.

Comment: Okay, if my answer is not clear yet above, post more code so as we can understand the question better.